My late husband, Thomas Bruce Meagher patent guru has 52 utility patents, as his widow should I get any royalities? It has not been 20 years for some
I am the Widow of Thomas Bruce Meagher patent guru, I lost my husband January 1 2010 in horrible accident. Thomas has 52 utility patents, it possible I could get royalities from 5 of my husband's 52 utility Patents because Until recently the patents were still only my husband was the only assignee and only inventor they were not signed over.
I cannot get information from his employer,or his lawyer, 5 of the patents Thomas was only Inventor and only assignee, this was recently I noticed this change, maybe about a year or so ago. Is this possible can
a company sign patents over to themselves,If the widow is not contacted, can someone else change the assignee and inventor. I

If he was an employee at the time of the invention then most likely the company he worked for would own the patent and rights to any licensing income. If he was receiving royalties to a patent that is still unexpired then you might have rights to those payments. Otherwise owning a patent gives the owner the right to sue someone who is infringing on the patent. All that requires consulting with an intellectual property lawyer.
Update:
I've done a search and as far as I can tell there are 30 granted, active patents and 19 applications. All of these are assigned or owned by Ics Triplex Technology Ltd or Rockwell Automation Limited. I think it is highly unlikely that Mr. Meagher received royalties and that those are available to you.

If a company owns the patent, they can do whatever they want with it just like any owner. To be clear, every indication I can find indicates the companies have legally owned the patents you are concerned with.

I agree they can Eric, when I wrote in to stackexchange for the first time. 5 patents were  not sign over to the company, up y
